# Removing index.php from Magento URL While Using Nginx

Tags: magento, nginx

My current setup is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Nginx 1.4.1, with Magento 1.7.0.2.

Earlier today, I set up a basic Magento store.  I haven't installed any modules and I haven't made any configuration changes.  I'm just looking to get the groundwork laid before delving further into the system.  I am looking to remove the "index.php" that appears between the domain name and the file path.

My vhost is taken from the nginx website:

```
server {
  root     /path/to/root/domain/html;
  index    index.php;
  error_log /path/to/error/log/error.log;
  access_log /path/to/transfer/log/transfer.log;
  server_name   servername.com;
  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
  }

  location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ {     internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

I see that other people have have been searching for the answer to this question, there are code snippets to solutions, but none of these appear to work with my system.  When I make changes to my Nginx vhost, I always restart nginx, but index.php still shows up in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx config looks fine. In `system > configuration > general > web` in your admin panel set `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `yes` and clear the cache in magento.

Comment: If can't acces to dashboard for 4040 how can modify this value on shell or datrabase?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to magento nginx vhost.

```
 location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
            }
            if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
                    expires max;
                    break;
            }
    }
```